# Run a task in the background that waits until a certain word is entered in the terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh

I want to run a background set of commands from the terminal as a script or function that waits until a certain command is entered in the foreground. I don't want to wait for just a keypress, I need the word, string or character + enter. I've tried stuff like reading the last command in bash history but I am getting nowhere.

```
sh -c "until [ "$(history | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')" = donut ];\
do : ; done; echo 'Why did you just type donut you doughnut? \
That is not even a word let alone a command.' &" &

sh -c "until [ "$(history | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')" = ":" ]; do sleep 1 ; done; echo gotcha" &
```

Ideally I dont want any output like 'command not found' if the word is not a command and I don't want the word to execute if it is a command. That's why I tried the : command it is both and neither.

I also tried looking for `":\n"` in various ways. I'm probably barking up the wrong tree here with the history command and suspect something to do with `cat /dev/tty` is required.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd be leaning towards a tty-based solution; take a look at this [answer: read/write to tty* device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138390/234539) for some basics; if you're still having problems I'd suggest opening a new question and provide details on what you've tried via ttys

Comment: @markp-fuso : Thank you for providing the link. I always thought that a process which has been put in the background, can not interact with the tty anymore. Since the parent (i.e. foreground) process is the interactive shell and has still control over the tty as well, wouldn't the background process block if he wants to open the same tty?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your operating system. For Mac, you need to create an executable file in your /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin. That is the directory where all the bash commands are executing from. You'll find things like "time", or "python", or "whoami" stored there. The actual executable can be anything, but you're trying to keep things simple, use a python script with a shebang. Then make the file into a unix executable. The actual program can be very simple, just force quit the process id of the "background process". I'm not sure how Windows organizes their "bin", but it's probably something similar.

Comment: slightly off topic